# Why do we count years from the date of Creation?

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, calendar, creation

Why do we count years from the date of Creation? I intend two sub-questions here, of which the second is far more interesting, so please answer it:

1. Whence did this tradition originate?
2. Why do we continue doing it when it is [so](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9747/1516) [problematic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16605/1516), that is, nonstraightforward? The answers linked discuss how a "day" in Biblical Creation is most often understood as a figurative interval that actually corresponds to a much longer period. Obviously, as Biblical history progresses, the time-scale quickly shifts to be in line with a modern one. Still, isn't it misleading to imply that we are literally 5772 years from the date of Creation?

Comment: How will answers to this question differ substantially from [the one to which you linked](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30/berieshit-vs-science/16605)?

Comment: I like the heading of the question much more than the breakdown of the question into two parts. I agree with @yoel that to answer #2, one would essentially have to copy/paste the answer to the linked question. -1.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason I liked the question initially upon reading the heading is because I thought it was primarily about #1 vis a vis the old tradition of counting years from significant events (years of a king's reign, for example, or Christianity and Islam's traditions of counting from their significant "starting" points); following that tradition it might make the most sense to count from Yetziath Mitzrayim.

Comment: @SethJ *that* would be an interesting question - why we count from the first man instead of the first Jew.

Comment: @yoel, I was thinking of the Kuzari when I wrote my comment, but yours is an interesting twist as well.

Comment: @SethJ I confess I don't know the Kuzari well enough to make the connection.

Comment: @yoel The Kuzari tells a story of how a king summoned emissaries of the three monotheistic religions and asked them to make their case and he would convert. The Christian and Muslim both started with, "In the beginning, G-d created the world..." The Jew started with, "G-d took us out of Egypt." The king asked him, "Wait, what about creating the world?" The Jew responded, "Well that's a given. You asked about Judaism."

Comment: @SethJ got it - I knew the premise, but it's interesting, and maybe it's an answer to the question - the creation of the world is just the most basic and obvious starting point.

Comment: @SethJ: wasn't the Jew's answer basically that the events of the Exodus - which that first generation experienced personally, and passed down to us - prove that G-d created the world?

Comment: @Alex, that's his proof of accuracy. But IINM he also focused on it as _the_ important starting point in Jewish history and the reason we worship G-d (ie., while Creation was necessary, _this_ - our salvation and chosenness - is the reason we have a religion).

Comment: I stand by [the second part of] my question, but I think I had and continue to have some trouble phrasing it in a way that demonstrates why it is meaningful. I guess I'm trying to say, why use what is essentially a figurative construct as the basis for a way to count something as literal (and practically important) as years in a modern historical record? In other words, why build on such shaky ground?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first question is a duplicate of [When did we start counting the Year since Creation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11317/883)

In answer to your second question, I have no source, but I would be shocked if the answer was more complex than that the originators of this counting system simply believed (as many still do, myself included) that it was completely accurate.

I suppose that those rabbis that don't believe it to be accurate could have switched to a system based on something more concrete yet still significant, like the Exodus, the Giving of the Torah, or better yet, the Beis Hamikdash. The reason this hasn't happened is most likely because that would simply overcomplicate things, when all rabbinic writings already use the other system. There is no benefit to switching to a more accurately dated system, when all systems are relative, and the one in use is simply based on an arbitrary (ITO) point in time.

Edit: As DoubleAA points out, there are rabbis who are attempting to change the system, although their lack of success at becoming the prevalent standard (so far) is likely due to the reason outlined in the above paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

Rav Yaaqov Medan wrote [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315062909/http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/parsha65/15-65bo.htm) about using the Exodus from Egypt as the reference point for years on 5/11/315. That's right: he wrote it on the 5th of Shevat in the year 3315 AE (After the Exodus). He claims to use that notation for all of his "dating in memoranda that he sends to academics, legalists and government officials with whom he comes into contact, and never has any one of them raised any objection." You'll notice that [his Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaaqov_Medan) lists his birth year as 3263.

So it seems that as of today, 10/3/324, at least some people are pushing for change.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Maybe we should adopt this as the Mi.Yodeya standard! :)

Comment: That date has just as many problems as the creation of the world date!  (From creation to Exodus it's easy to count the years, from Exodus forwards it's very difficult!)

I have however seen some use the current year as 67, as in 67 years since we reconqured Israel.

Comment: @avi Depends if you understand the creation date to include or exclude sheshet yemei vereishit.

Comment: The official calendar is from the date Adam left the Garden I believe. The "6 days" are actually all pre-calendar.

Comment: @avi I don't know how you can prove one way or another. Certainly the OP doesn't seem to assume as much.

Comment: There are many drashot which discuss the issue. Birchat Hachama for example is not the 4th of Tishrei

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. I recommend converting to a comment.

Comment: @msh an answer that we shouldnt seems appropriate to his question why continue doing this problematic thing

Answer (score 3):

In this question, [Destruction of the world after 1000 years of Moshiach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15889/destruction-of-the-world-after-1000-years-of-moshiach), Shmuel Brin in the course of his answer says,

> Regarding the seventh millenium, the Gemara says (Sanhedrin 97a) that
>   "Six thousand years the world will exist and for one it will be
>   destroyed".

and there are other references in answers as to what will happen after 6000 years.

Therefore we need to know where we are up to in that process and so must count years from the date of Creation.

Comment: Why do we need to know how far along we are?

Comment: @msh210 Fair question. No good answer other than to be informed and have perspective.

Comment: To plan our investments wisely? Why invest now if the world will end tomorrow?

Answer (score 1):

The tradition of counting from the creation of the world (anno mundi, or AM, vs. anno domini, or AD) comes from various texts of the Middle Ages. Counting from the creation of the world was common through the eighteenth century in many general histories as well, though the Enlightenment tradition critiqued such historical views (such as AM and organizing the history of the world into the four kingdoms of Daniel) as antiquated and unhelpful. This is tied to a broader reconceptualization of the landscape of history with the rise of the concept of the century.

This trend can be seen, for example, in texts such as the Sefer Ha-Qabbalah (Ibn Daud), who wanted to show the long and unbroken chain of the Jewish tradition. Thus, the counting of years from the creation of the world is inherently part of religious polemics.

First, against the Karaites, Ibn Daud wanted to demonstrate that the Jewish oral tradition (the Talmud) came from Moses.

Second, against the Christians, Jews in Europe (not ibn Daud) wanted to demonstrate that a Christian proof for the divinity of Jesus -- a messianic calculation, that the date of Jesus' birth was in the year 6,000 AM, similar to the many Jewish predictions of the messiah -- was incorrect because the Christians had calculated the calendar incorrectly.

Comment: Can you edit into the answer a source for your claims, particularly your claims of what ibn Daud wanted? Otherwise, we have only your word for it, and, no offense, but most of us don't know you.

Comment: I've read Sefer Ha-Qabbalah. There is no online source I can point to. Regarding the Christian Polemic, see Yisrael Yuval's work.

Comment: @msh210 He cited the book, no? You want him to cite a summary?

Comment: Jason, you cited ibn Daud as using dates AM, which I trust you on, but then you claimed sourcelessly that his intent in so doing was to show the long chain of tradition and to counter arguments of the Karaites and Christians. That's what I was seeking a source for, edited into the answer. Ping @DoubleAA.

Comment: Sorry it is not clear. I will update it.

Comment: By the way, the issue of what is a "source" is really moot. I see an answer to this very question that says, straight up, that "I have no source," and on this site generally there are many people who write "I heard once that such-and-such a rabbi said" and that is not given such criticism.

Comment: @Jason, I meant no criticism: I was only asking you to edit in any citation you may have. Clearly, someone saying "I have no source" or "I once heard from X" has no further citation, so there's no point in asking for one.

Comment: The Greek [Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) does indeed possess a different chronology than the Masoretic tradition, ascribing roughly the same amount of years before Noah's *birth* as the latter sets before Noah's *Flood*. Then, from the Flood unto Terah's birth, it counts *exactly* one thousand years, instead of just 290. The [Samaritan Pentateuch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritan_Pentateuch) is a blend of these two ancient Jewish reckonings. The LXX seems keen on putting an even five millennia before the  Hellenistic & Ptolemaic era, to which it owes its existence.

Answer (score -2):

As I answered in [When did we start counting the Year since Creation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11317/when-did-we-start-counting-the-year-since-creation/87199#87199), until the establishment of the State of Israel, **we didn't really "count" Hebrew years, we "calculated" them**.

All existing systems are based on calculating Hebrew years, **based on Torah events and common sense logic**. Hebrew years were never counted.

Comment: Do you mean people didn't know the Hebrew year from year to year and needed to recalculate? That is false.

Comment: @mevaqesh As I tried to make clear, we did not COUNT, as in Omer, like on Rosh Hashana pounding on the Bama and declaring "today is תשנ"ה" from the Creation. We knew the years by calculating them, as Seder Olam and Rambam did. We don't have a tradition of counting, hence the arguments. Can you please find me a source for Jewish community where all official year counting was based on Creation?