# First year counted from creation

Tags: history, calendar, time, creation

What is the first year for which there exists a record of it being dated according to the currently used system that starts counting from creation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11317/when-did-we-start-counting-the-year-since-creation?rq=1

Comment: @HodofHod I'm not sure. Alex's answer there is about the origins of the number in the count not where we see it being used. I realize we judge by question, but maybe with some editing we can distinguish the separate question.

Comment: Definite duplicate. @DoubleAA, the other question seeks the earliest reference to its use, and this seeks the earliest record of its use. Unless the other asker was specifically seeking some work of history rather than an original source (which would seem like an odd request, IMHO), I think they're identical.

Comment: @SethJ That question did not ask for a specific year. Furthermore, Alex doesn't provide a source that we know follows our count. As avi's source indicates there were multiple traditions floating around.

Comment: [Bereishis Rabah 9:14](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/raba1/9.htm) is relevant to this.

Comment: I believe the count comes from the beginning of Adam's life. That might be implied, but 'creation' was not clear to me.

Answer (score -1):

[3,925  about 5 years after the Seder Haolam was written.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Mundi#cite_note-2)

Comment: Avi, is that a guess - or is there a specific usage that you're referring to?

Comment: @IsaacZ My guess is that the book cited in note #3 of the Wikipedia entry should have a more specific reference to guide his reference.

Comment: @IsaacZ You will want to check page 107 of Mattis, Kantor, The Jewish time line encyclopedia: a year-by-year history from Creation to present, Jason Aronson Inc., Northvale, N.J., 1992  to find out if it's a guess or known.